# Is there a Ruby on Rails messaging service equivalent to JMS (Java Messaging Service)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jms, message-queue

I am a Java programmer that has been converted to Ruby so please excuse the java references here.  I am trying to design a system that can update a web page based on external inputs that arrive randomly.  So every once in a while, I will have something new to put on the web screen. This is where I was wondering if there is a Messaging Queue built into Ruby that I could listen to for when these updates occur?  If this were java, I would use a JMS queue here.  Is there a Ruby on Rails equivalent to JMS queue I can use?

Google has turned up some old references (2009) to JRuby (which is not what I need).

Answer (score 1):

You could try [redis](http://redis.io/) with [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) which implements pubsub and message queues. And you can also use redis standalone to get a subset of the functionality.